# Is there a way to view the clans I've been in?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there a way I can view the clans I've been in, in the past? Was just looking to go back to a friends clan but I've forgotten its name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go to clash of stats and go history, previous clans. Hope this helps[image]

Comment: Also, go to bookmarks on the game

Answer (score 1):

The only way to view past clans is to look over any past clan mail you have gotten. If there was no clan mail from that clan, or it was pushed out of your inbox, you have no way of reaching it.